# Java class hierarchy, how to implement optional variable throughout

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm wondering if there's any "clean" way to implement an optional variable throughout a class hierarchy without simply leaving it null and nullchecking all the time. Let's say I have the following abstract parent class:

```
public abstract class Item {

public String name;

public Item(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

Pretty straightforward. Now I have another abstract class that extends this and a couple more that extend that one, each with a few additional variables/methods of their own. Item also has a stub class extending it (nothing but a constructor that calls super()) that may not be necessary if Item can be made concrete, but that depends on the solution.

Now, let's say that any of these concrete classes could potentially contain an instance of MyObject. A large number of Items will be created. Some of the instances of any of the classes in the Item hierarchy will have it and some won't. There's no way for the program to tell at compile time. I can't really split the hierarchy into two separate but nearly-identical trees, one with MyObject and one without. That's going to lead to a lot of code duplication. Subclassing the concrete implementations with another concrete class containing MyObject would mean excessive typechecking, which would get ugly, especially if the hierarchy grows. Putting an interface/abstract class further up isn't an option either as that would put MyObject in everything. Regardless of the solution, all of these must have a common interface/abstract class.

I may be nitpicking and should just implement MyObject at the top of the hierarchy and nullcheck it or use a simple boolean method to tell me if it's present or not, but it still feels a bit sloppy to me and I'd like to find a better solution if possible.

Comment: No clean way. Usually this means your class hierachy is a bit whacky and should refactored...

Comment: I tried, but I could find no reasonable way of refactoring it to separate the two. The presence of MyObject adds an extra piece of functionality, but does nothing to change any other fields/methods in each Item. Classes outside of this will iterate over Collections of Items and determine which have MyObject, which will separate them (at least as far as the user sees, not literally in the code) based on that additional functionality. Think of it as a list of various cars with and without A/C, but if A/C is present, we need to know what kind, how it functions, etc. A simple flag won't do.

Comment: Did you consider removing the optional parts from the hierarchy and using composition to place them where needed?

Comment: I don't think Composition will do the trick here. The way this is built is that Items are largely containers of data that don't have much in the way of behavior. For example, a view may be presented that has a list of Items by their name variable. Clicking on one will bring up details on that Item along with possible actions that can be taken, and those actions are based on various attributes of the Item. I could look into making those actions and what is presented based on behaviors somehow directly in/directly related to each Item, but that could be tricky...

Comment: Okay, I think I have a solution that is not perfect, but cleaner. Item is now an interface for two concrete classes: MyObjectItem and StandardItem. This way a single type check will determine if MyObject is present, which isn't perfect, but cleaner than a null check IMHO. Each of these contains a WrappedItem, which is now the parent class for the former Item subclasses. It's an extra layer, but it seems to work out well enough, and I think I may have found a way to eliminate some of the typechecking that was being done on them before.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of problem reminds me the very motivation for the Decorator pattern - an overgrown class hierarchy with some kind of wanted "multiple inheritance" and "combination of super-classes". Have a look at the description of [Decorator](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) on internet, and for good example have a look at how the [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) / Writer standard Java classes are implemented.